# How to supply enviroment variable while serving a node js project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, serve

I have created a React js application using ["create-react-app"](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) .

In my App.js code , I am accessing enviroment variable like:

```
console.log('ucm host port',process.env.REACT_APP_API_HOST ,process.env.REACT_APP_API_PORT); //Point-1
```

In the my development environment, when I run my application by executing below command

```
sudo REACT_APP_API_HOST=localhost REACT_APP_API_PORT=5050 npm start
```

I am able to access these runtime supplied environment variable values at "Point-1" at my App.js code,
Now I want to build and packages by App/Project, So I did

```
sudo npm run build
```

I got a "build" directory of my project, which I am able to distribute to other servers/teams and access my webpages(App.js), by executing  below command

```
sudo serve -s build
```

But while I distribute the "build" folder to other team, I want to change the environment variable values during "serve" command, like

```
sudo REACT_APP_API_HOST=someOther_host REACT_APP_API_PORT=9090 serve -s build
```

But when I do this, I cant access these new values at "point-1" of code.
How to supply enviroment values to my code during 'serve' command ?

Note:
When I tried below during build time, I am able to get these values during 'serve' command, but I can't change them

```
sudo REACT_APP_API_HOST=localhost REACT_APP_API_PORT=5050  npm run build
```

Comment: You cannot edit your env variables while serving built files because they don't exist. The values of the variables are hardcoded in your build.

Comment: Ok, but In that case I have to create one "build" for each team, its like, I hardcode the IP address during creating .jar file.
Is there any other way ? Should I go for like use nginx or apache ?